# Site auto refreshing when using reveal.js+socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, reveal.js

I have 3 iframes with reaveal.js presentations. And while they are not on node.js server they.re working perfectly. But I need socket.io to auto-refresh selected iframe when conents of file with reveal.js presentation is changed (I'm uploading a file using php manipulate it and making new .html file with presentation then I'm overwriting the old file).
Node.js server with chokidar is watching for change of file. And it's working.
But everything if failing when I'm joining socket.io and reveal.js together.
Site is constntly refreshing (don't know why i exluded emits) and because of that browser is crashing.

Server code:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var fs = require('fs');
var chokidar = require('chokidar');


app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

// io.on('connection', function (socket) {
//   socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
//   socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
//     console.log(data);
//   });
// });

var watcher = chokidar.watch('file, dir, or glob', {
  ignored: /[\/\\]\./, persistent: true
});
watcher.add('prez/prez1.html');
watcher.add('prez/prez2.html');
watcher.add('prez/prez3.html');
var log = console.log.bind(console);

watcher
  .on('change', function(path) { log('File', path, 'changed');
  //io.emit('restart1');


   })
```

Client code:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
 var socket = io('http://localhost');
  // socket.on('news', function (data) {
  //   console.log(data);
  //   socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  // });
//   socket.on('restart1', function (data) {



// var iframe = document.getElementById('ramka1');
// iframe.src = iframe.src;


//   });
//   socket.on('restart2', function (data) {
//    var iframe = document.getElementById('ramka2');
// iframe.src = iframe.src;
//   });
//   socket.on('restart3', function (data) {

//    var iframe = document.getElementById('ramka3');
// iframe.src = iframe.src;
//   });

</script>


         <iframe id="ramka1" width="100%" height="33%" src="prez/prez1.html"></iframe><br>
         <iframe id="ramka2" width="100%" height="33%" src="prez/prez2.html"></iframe><br>
         <iframe id="ramka3" width="100%" height="33%" src="prez/prez3.html"></iframe><br>
<style type="text/css">
      iframe {
         border:none;
     }  
     </style>

    </body>
</html>
```

Example presentation code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reveal.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme/white.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="reveal">
            <div class="slides">
                <section>Slide 1</section>
                <section>Slide 2</section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/reveal.js"></script>
        <script>
            Reveal.initialize({controls: false, loop: true,  autoSlide: 1000});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```